# Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, console.log

I'm using Selenium to run tests in Chrome via the Python , and I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure Chrome to make the console.log output from the loaded test available.

i cant get opject values.

my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)
driver.get("https://ex.com/")
time.sleep(10)
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    try:
        print(entry)
        print("\n\n")
```

```
{'level': 'INFO', 'message': 'https://palringo.im/scripts/palringo-web-bundle.js 1729:14 "(PalringoChats) onMessage [group]" Object', 'source': 'console-api', 'timestamp': 1583885800571}
output:
```

the console on chrome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oVqe.png)

I want to receive all data shown in the image.

thanks.

Comment: You can restore this problem of getting the string "object" instead of the actual JSON object by scraping "https://www.iaa.gov.il/airports/ben-gurion/flight-board" with 35 seconds of sleep